# Checking Url if it starts with "http" or "https", is it possible that a non-secure Url starts with "https"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, https, http-post

I am publishing my website to an IIS server which I don't have control over, and I want to understand from codebehind that if it's URL starts with "http" or "https".

First, I tried these two solutions on my local, and both returned the correct value ("http"):

```
this.Request.Url.Scheme 

Request.IsSecureConnection
```

To be sure, I also installed a secure SSL connection to my own computer's IIS, and published the same code. Both these codes grabbed the correct value (https) there too.

However, when I publish it to the IIS server of my company, which uses "https", it returns as "http" instead.

What would be the issue here? I noticed that the URL I am trying might not be considered a secure layer even it starts with "https" (It is not turning green and shown as secure when I call the page from Google Chrome) so maybe it's not a secure layer it's only a regular page only starts with "https" instead of http. Is this kind of scenario possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility could be that you have a proxy or load balancer in front of your web application. It may be 'offloading' the SSL prior to reaching your site.

Also, as you point out, simply specifying https in the browser does not guarantee that your SSL certificate is working and configured correctly. Try a tool like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to help identify the issue.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I am thinking of some kind of proxy barrier is possible. I certainly know something replaces all the "http" requests with "https" requests. 

But the webpage passed from the test of the the tool you advised. It means that I actually is a secure website, but these code blocks returns "http" anyway. 

As far I as understand, you basicly say "There is something on IIS that responsible for converting "http" to "https" in the requests, but your code can't understand that and acts like it's http anyway." Is that correct? Do you have an idea about how to prove/avoid this?

Comment: Imagine data being transferred across a chain like this: User -> Internet -> Load Balancer -> Server -> Application. In this case it is common to only transfer over SSL from the User to the Load Balancer, but to not bother between the Load Balancer and the Application. You can have the same scenario if we imagine a Proxy in the chain. This can make it more difficult for your application to check the original scheme. However usually the original scheme will be placed in a header such as X-Forwarded-Proto. This is a big topic, but Google about X-Forwarded-Proto and SSL offloading.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the details.